# Herokuapp - Google Oauth - Hackmd/Codimd

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-oauth, internal-server-error, hackmd

### Description

I am using Hackmd on a heroku container since 1-2 year with google oauth. No Problems - Google Oauth worked before. Today was my first access since 3 weeks but then suddenly on login orcurred "Internal Server Error" Before the weeks it worked perfectly fine. There weren't any changes in that time.
Does anybody know something about that or even a fix or workaround?

### Stacktrace

`2019-10-28T15:58:02.257474+00:00 app[web.1]: Error
2019-10-28T15:58:02.257484+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:95:21
2019-10-28T15:58:02.257486+00:00 app[web.1]:     at passBackControl (/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
2019-10-28T15:58:02.257488+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
2019-10-28T15:58:02.257489+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
2019-10-28T15:58:02.257491+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
2019-10-28T15:58:02.257492+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
2019-10-28T15:58:02.257494+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
2019-10-28T15:58:02.257495+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
2019-10-28T15:58:02.261785+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-10-28T15:58:02.261Z - info: ::ffff:10.196.48.88 - - [28/Oct/2019:15:58:02 +0000] "GET /auth/google/callback?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile HTTP/1.1" 500 148 "http://domain.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36"`

(I changed the code value and domain)

### Software

- Hackmd Doopio
- Heroku Stack *heroku-16*

Comment: Hey, in case you want to continue using the community project: it has been renamed to CodiMD and now lives here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594803/herokuapp-google-oauth-hackmd-codimd
A lot has happened since that release, maybe that fixes your problem.

Comment: Just giving the correct url https://github.com/hackmdio/codimd

Comment: actually, the correct url to the community fork is this one: https://github.com/codimd/server, be aware that they are in the process of renaming and will be named HedgeDoc soon.

Comment: Hedgedoc is currently on v1.9.0 with no means for upgrading from CodiMD >1.6.0 or HackMD > 1.1.0 (see https://docs.hedgedoc.org/setup/getting-started/#migrating-from-codimd-hackmd). I've been running `hackmdio/hackmd` (the official container image for CodiMD - I know it's confusing) for years as a self-hosted project, and it's currently on v2.4.1. No matter how you feel about the bitter war between HackMD/CodiMD/Hedgedoc, releasing a "new" product that is a complete major version behind is not a step forward for the community.